# NSBundle with image asset inside

Tags: objective-c, macos, frameworks

What I am doing is a framework with resources. I can use resources such as images copied to framework, but i wanna use image asset catalog with method like imageNamed:
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Your image asset catalog's name into the Method NSImage imageNamed:

[image]

In this case You can use as

```
NSImage *aImg = [NSImage imageNamed:@"YourImageAsset"];
```

Comment: This is an OSX question where `UIImage` does not exist.

Comment: I know how to use it in application! The question was about how to use it inside my framework implementation. imageNamed: not works!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bundle for your framework and use `-[NSBundle imageForResource:]`.